# How to put a FOR loop in a WHILE loop

Tags: matrix, procedural-programming, random

I have a strange matrix like this one in the picture

[image]

Now, my goal is to change all the 1s with random complex numbers of modulus 1, but if the element $a_{12}=z$, then $a_{21}= \bar{z}$, so the complex conjugate of $z$.

In the code CAC is this starting matrix, PCAC is the "complex" matrix I want to create.
Nn is the "size" of squares of zeros inside (5x5 in this case, so Nn=5).

```
PCAC = CAC;
j = 2;
While[j <= 2 Nn + 1,
 θ = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
 PCAC[[1, j]] = Exp[I θ];
 PCAC[[j, 1]] = Exp[-I θ];
 j = j + 1;
 ]
a = 2;
While[a <= Nn + 1;
 For[i = 1, i <= Nn, i++,
  γ = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
  PCAC[[a, Nn + 1 + i]] = Exp[I γ];
  PCAC[[Nn + 1 + i, a]] = Exp[-I γ];
   ];
 a=a+1;
 ]
MatrixForm[PCAC]
```

**My problem**

With the first *while* loop, I fill the first row and the first column. Everything ok.

Then I fill with complex numbers the "squares inside" but it's like that the second *while* loop doesn't work (and the *for* loop works).
Here there is what I get:

[image]

Why the *while* loop does not continue after changing the second row and column?

Comment: Your second `While[a<=Nn+1;For[...];a=a+1]` I think that semicolon before the `For` should be a comma instead. As you have it I think the `For` and the `a=a+1` are all part of the `While` condition.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the comma instead of ; Thank you! Sorry for that stupid problem

Comment: No sorry's, not for me. If I'd NEVER made a mistake like that then maybe. But with all the compute power we have sitting there idle, before we actually start running the code, doesn't it seem like it could be scanning the code in the background and up would pop a "purple bouncing fickle finger" showing us where there is likely something really really wrong that we just haven't noticed yet. Consider the kinds of common mistakes that most of us humans make and the machine doesn't bounce that finger on that telling us "look here, look here, this is really really likely a dumb mistake."

Comment: This can be done more simply. I defined `cac` as `Normal[...]` where `...` denotes the construction in the response by @Edmund. Then simply replace 1's and add the result to its conjugate transpose, like so. `In[344]:= cacb = cac /. 1 :> Exp[2*I*Pi*RandomReal[]];
cacRandHerm = cacb + ConjugateTranspose[cacb];
HermitianMatrixQ[cacRandHerm]

Out[346]= True`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is, "Don't".

Create `CAC`.

```
CAC =
 SparseArray[
  {
   {1, 1} -> 0
   , Band[{2, 2}, {11, 11}] -> {ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}]}
   }, {11, 11}, 1]
```

Position of 1's in upper triangular.

```
pos = Position[UpperTriangularize[CAC], 1];
```

Random complex numbers of modulus 1 in upper triangular.

```
PCAC = ReplacePart[CAC, Thread[pos -> Exp[I RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, Length@pos]]]];
```

Conjugate of upper triangular in lower triangular

```
With[{ut = UpperTriangularize[PCAC]},
  PCAC = ut + Transpose[Conjugate[ut]]
  ];
MatrixForm[PCAC]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Complex number with a unity Norm:

```
rNormOne := Module[{\[Theta]},
  \[Theta] = RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}];
  r = Cos[\[Theta]] + I Sin[\[Theta]]
  ]

amat = {{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  , {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  , {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  , {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  , {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  , {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  , {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  , {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  , {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  , {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  , {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  }
```

Check:

```
HermitianMatrixQ[amat]
```

> (* True *)

LowerTriangularize and substitute a random Complex number for each `1` entry.

```
(lt = (LowerTriangularize[amat] /. 1 :> rNormOne)  /. (0. + 0. I) -> 
      0 // Chop) // MatrixForm
```

Generate upper triangular matrix:

```
(ut = ConjugateTranspose[lt]) // MatrixForm
```

Join:

```
(newMat = ut + lt) // MatrixForm

HermitianMatrixQ[newMat]
```

> (* True *)

```
Map[Norm, newMat, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$